# XCode 4.2 - Openssl build error

Tags: xcode, openssl, ios-simulator

I have successfully created the OpenSSL library for iPhone Simulator. I have successfully imported all the headers and libs. However, I am having problems in building the project and XCode tells me that there is an **incomplete definition of a struct X509_ALGOR**. Here is the code:

```
- (NSData *)encodePBEWithMD5AndDESData:(NSData *)inData password:(NSString *)password direction:(int)direction
{   
// Change salt and number of iterations for your project !!!

static const char gSalt[] =
{
    (unsigned char)0xaa, (unsigned char)0xd1, (unsigned char)0x3c, (unsigned char)0x31,
    (unsigned char)0x53, (unsigned char)0xa2, (unsigned char)0xee, (unsigned char)0x05
};

unsigned char *salt = (unsigned char *)gSalt;
int saltLen = strlen(gSalt);
int iterations = 15;

EVP_CIPHER_CTX cipherCtx;


unsigned char *mResults;         // allocated storage of results
int mResultsLen = 0;

const char *cPassword = [password UTF8String];

unsigned char *mData = (unsigned char *)[inData bytes];
int mDataLen = [inData length];    

SSLeay_add_all_algorithms();
X509_ALGOR *algorithm = PKCS5_pbe_set(NID_pbeWithMD5AndDES_CBC,
                                      iterations, salt, saltLen);


memset(&cipherCtx, 0, sizeof(cipherCtx));

if (algorithm != NULL)
{
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(&(cipherCtx));

    **if (EVP_PBE_CipherInit(algorithm->algorithm, cPassword, strlen(cPassword),
                           algorithm->parameter, &(cipherCtx), direction))**
    {

        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding(&cipherCtx, 1);

        int blockSize = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_block_size(&cipherCtx);
        int allocLen = mDataLen + blockSize + 1; // plus 1 for null terminator on decrypt
        mResults = (unsigned char *)OPENSSL_malloc(allocLen);


        unsigned char *in_bytes = mData;
        int inLen = mDataLen;
        unsigned char *out_bytes = mResults;
        int outLen = 0;
```

The pointer to struct X509_ALGOR, which is 'algorithm' is found to be incompletely defined. I don't have any clue about this. Can anyone help me please?

```
if (EVP_PBE_CipherInit(algorithm->algorithm, cPassword, strlen(cPassword),
                           algorithm->parameter, &(cipherCtx), direction))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is appropriate to post answer to my own question. However, I am doing this if someone has the same problem, he/she may get some help from this.

The problem with the above mentioned code was the linker flags. Once I set the "-ObjC -load_all" in "Other Linker Flags" under "Build Settings", the problem was gone.

Regards.